# Fill an empty dataframe by rows with paired ratios of rows of another dataframe

Tags: r, function, loops, dataframe

I have a dataframe, for all columns of which I want to calculate paired ratios of rows (for example, row1/row2, row3/row4, row5/row6, etc.) and write the result of calculation to a new dataframe. I decided to wrap it in a function with 3 arguments:

```
paired_row_rat=function(dataframe,rows,columns){
ratio_df=data.frame(matrix(nrow=rows/2,ncol=columns)) #creates new dataframe 
#where number of columns is the same as in dataframe used for 
#calculation, number of rows for paired ratios will be 2 times lower  

cln=colnames(dataframe)     #names of columns should be equal in both
colnames(ratio_df)=cln      #dataframes                        

i=seq(1,rows,by=2) #sequance for choosing the first row of calculation
j=i+1              #for choosing second row of calculation

  for (k in 1:nrow(ratio_df)){              #here as I am trying to fill new
    ratio_df[k,]=dataframe[i,]/dataframe[j,] #dataframe with ratios, 
  }                                          #the error appears
  return(ratio_df)
}
pmap(list(tula3,24,98),paired_row_rat)          
#runs the function for my dataframe with 24 rows and 98 columns
```

In the resulting dataframe each column has the same values for all rows and I have warnings from R:

> warnings()
>   Warning messages:
>   1: In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, k, , value = structure(list( ... :
>     replacement element 1 has 12 rows to replace 1 rows

I've searched a lot for possible solutions but still can't fix this problem. Something is wrong with the for loop. But I don't uderstand where the problem is.

datafrfame used for calculation (the result of head(df)):
[image: datafrfame used for calculation (the result of head(df))]

Comment: Over the top of my head, I think you need to have 2 loops, one for each row and one for each column. Lets say that I have a 2*2 matrix. I will need one `i` and one `j` to have calculated the value of each element in the matrix.

Comment: `seq(1,rows,by=2)` How is `rows` defined? `i`is a sequence not a single number. Right!? `i`will not just index one row.

Comment: number of **rows** is the argument of the function, so it's defined when using the function on a dataframe. **i** is a suquence.

Comment: Yeah, but if `row` is let's say `7` then the result will be `seq(1,7,by=2)` ==> `1 3 5 7` which will select `4` rows in your `dataframe`and you are trying to replace one row accoring to `k` in `ratio_df`

Comment: @burton030 the number of rows is supposed to be even (2 rows reperesent 2 different states of 1 point). The database I am using in the example has 24 rows.

Comment: Maybe I get it wrong. But if `rows` is `24` this will result in `ratio_df[k,]=dataframe[1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23,]/dataframe[2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24,]` which will give you `12` numbers and you try to fill these  `12` numbers in one row in `ratio_df`.

Comment: @burton030 may be that is what is happening. But I want **for** loop to calculate ratios for pairs of rows (1/2,3/4,5/6,7/8 ets.) of a dataframe and fill new dataframe with these ratios. How should I change the **for** loop to have output I need? Do I need to change the definition of **i** and **j**?

Comment: See Tushar's coomen `dataframe[i[k],]/dataframe[j[k],]` should do the trick. `k`will index your created vector. In this way you will only divide one row by the other which will result in one row. What you could also do is to define `k`as an vector let's say `k=1:12` or `k = 1:rows` or something.. This should also work. Maybe in this way you can also get rid of the `for` loop. Depending on what you want to achieve you can try around what is more feasable

Comment: please tell how you are calling the function?

Comment: @Tushar pmap(list(tula3,rows=24,columns=98),paired_row_rat)

Comment: Please call the function paired_row rat like this: `paired_row_rat(dataframe = df,rows = 6,columns = 2)`.. I am not able to reproduce the issues you are facing. Also, pmap() is not defined in the sample code you shared.

Comment: pmap () is in my sample code (the line above last line). But it doesn't work properly with my function. When function is called directly as you advised everything is fine. Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: So that could be an issue with how pmap() is defined. It's not a standard base R function. The definition of pmap() is not there in the question.

Comment: @Tushar. pmap() is from purrr package. I agree that its performance is another question and may be if it will be crucial for my research I will try to figure out what causes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumed that the requirement is to calculate the ratio for pairs row1/row2, row3/row4 and so on....

Try this:

```
as.data.frame(t(sapply(seq(1,(nrow(df)-1),2),function(x,df){df[x,]/df[x+1,]},df)))
```

where df is your data.frame

Comment: Thank you. That does what I need. But I still want to understand how to write the for loop correctly for this case. For my future coding.

Comment: @Elena i and j are not indexes, they are vector of indexes. You need to replace dataframe[i,]/dataframe[j,] with dataframe[i[k],]/dataframe[j[k],]... since i and j are vectors of length 3, for each value of k there will be 3 values of ratio generated

Comment: @Elena burton0320's explanation is correct. Make the change as i suggested in the comment in the for loop.

Comment: thank you for your help and explanation. I changed the for loop as you advised:`paired_row_rat=function(dataframe,rows,columns){
  ratio_df=data.frame(matrix(nrow=rows/2,ncol=columns))
  cln=colnames(dataframe) 
  colnames(ratio_df)=cln
    
  i=seq(1,rows,by=2)
  j=i+1
 for(k in 1:nrow(ratio_df)){
   ratio_df[k,]=dataframe[i[k],]/dataframe[j[k],]
   }
}` When I run it on my dataframe I have an error message:Error in dataframe[i[k], ] : incorrect number of dimensions. But when I perform all steps outside the function everything works perfectly. I'd greatly appretiate any help.

Comment: The code you just wrote in the comment does not have return(ratio_df)...also make sure you are passing the correct values of rows and columns where rows ideally should be an even number.